# Signature Verification using OpenSSL

Tags: ssh, encryption, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have been experimenting with OpenSSL and OpenSSH and I have been unable to sign and verify using RSA key pairs.

I did the following

Generated key pairs:

```
$ ssh-genkey -b 2048 -t rsa <key-name>
```

I then created a message digest by:

```
$ openssl sha1 -sign <key-name> -out rsasign.bin ~/tmp/test.txt
```

I attempted to verify the signature using the corresponding public key:

```
$ openssl sha1 -verify <key-name>.pub -signature rsasign.bin ~/tmp/test.txt
```

Unfortunately, trying this returns the error:

```
unable to load key file
```

Can anyone see any problem with what I'm doing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I'm assuming you mean `ssh-keygen`, not `ssh-genkey` (also, my version requires the path be specified interactively, not via the command line, but the output's the same). :)

The problem is that OpenSSL uses a different format for public keys than SSH. You can still use SSH-generated keys, but you need to get the public key in a format that OpenSSL can understand. You can do this with the following command:

```
openssl rsa -in <key-name> -pubout -out public-key.pem
```

Where `public-key.pem` is the new file you'll create. Once I did this, the verification command you mentioned ran successfully, outputting only `Verified OK` for my test file.

Note that the above command requires the **private** key, not the public key; you can convert an SSH-style public key to an OpenSSL-style public key by running:

```
ssh-keygen -f <key-name>.pub -e -m public-key.pem
```

Where `public-key.pem` is once again the new file you'll create.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try it out when I get a chance, but I'm pretty sure you got it.